# Apache how to find my httpd.conf

Tags: apache

I am looking for the httpd.conf of my apache server,
i searched here and i found the  find / -name httpd.conf
but these are my results and i dont know which one to edit.

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf_pre_ea3/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache/conf_pre_ea3/original/httpd.conf
/usr/local/apache.ea3-buildok-confgen-failed/conf/httpd.conf
/home/cpeasyapache/src/modsecurity-apache/tests/regression/server_root/conf/httpd.conf
/home/cpeasyapache/src/httpd-2.4/docs/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute this at the command line:
`apache2ctl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

This will report which config file is used.